# maven surefire exclude by directory?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, surefire

I'm using maven surefire and need to exclude my integration tests.  My project layout is non-standard, I have src/main/com, src/test/com and src/integration/com.

By default when I run the test goal the integration tests and unit tests are run.  I would like to exclude the integration tests...  I've tired:

```
<excludes><exclude>**/integration/*</exclude></excludes>
```

But this results in no tests running.  I then added an includes for the test, but still no tests run:

```
<includes><include>**/test/*</include></includes>
```

The first integration that is executed is under src/integration/com...

Also, if it matters this project is a subproject, so maybe that effects the path to exclude?

Any pointers on why I can't exclude these integration tests?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a folder named `integration` under `src/test/com`?

Comment: Good thought, I checked and I don't.  The first integration test that is executed is under src/integration.  Edited my question to add the this.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is not possible because all the code is compiled into target/classes and its from their that the tests are run.  This means what I'm trying won't work because I'm trying to match a directory structure that's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Include / Exclude path  is relative on the default configuration of test 'src/test/java'.
And you can't have two sources for testing but you should use this alternative :

```
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/com</testSourceDirectory>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>TO DO</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <sources>
            <source>src/integration/com</source>
        </sources>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I'm confused though.   what is the build-helper doing?  I want to exclude the integration tests from running and testSourceDirectory is already set to src/test.

Comment: when you do : mvn clean test which dirs you have in target/*